# How to group the most similar items into groups of two with multiple data points?

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples, grouping

I work in education and want to take students' scores from multiple tasks and group the students into groups of two based on their multiple scores. I need students with the most similar scores grouped into pairs, basically. How would I go about doing this? I'm fairly inexperienced with code and was unsure of how to approach this. I'm using Python. For example, let's say a student makes a 50%, 100%, etc. I want the students with the most similar scores grouped into pairs (tuples of their names would be the ideal output). Each student has eight scores total that need to be factored into the code.
Thanks,
Rachael

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It ight help if you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output, and if you can, code for what you've found or tried based on your own research. As it is, this question is pretty vague, and solutions could range from sorting the scores and zipping the lists to cosine similarity to NMF to machine learning clustering algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You could run a 'nearest neighbor' algorithm.
For example:
See [scikit NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors)

You encode your scores as points in a 8-dim space (50% -> 0.5 for example) and run the algorithm with n=1.

```
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
neigh.fit(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use kmeans clustering. See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import numpy as np
    #insert your csv file as 2D numpy array without the header or row index. Your input data size should be total number of students * 8.
    X = np.array(input_data)
    #set n_clusters to half the number of students
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_students/2, random_state=0).fit(X)
    kmeans.labels_
```